# creating a Integration Services Project gives me a Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS error

Tags: ssis

i got a Visual Studio 2019 and I installed the data tools.

I can see now that I have the integration services option to create a project:
[image]

The problem is, when I select the project name and solution, when I click NEXT it gives me an error:
[image]

"its not possible to load file or assembly ".

I could find nothing about this over the internet, only some forums saying I should resinstall ( I did ), or manually find the DLL. I found a folder with some DLLS but I have no idea what to do here.

SQL Server is ok, services are ok.

EDIT::

I just found out that I dont have the version 15.

[image]

is there something i can do?

Comment: Try installing the latest version of [Integration Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects)

Comment: Thank you I gave up and installed VS 2017. got the right data tools after looking for hours for it. this should be way easier.